# Edit regular expression that skips ":" character

Tags: .net, regex

I have this string :
John Doe(1/2)
I need to get **John Doe**, **1** and **2** seperately.
I have this regular expression for that :

```
([\w.-[\d]][\w.\s-[\d]]+)|([0-9]+)
```

But if I have this kind of String :
John : Doe (1/2)

I want to get **John : Doe** and **1** and **2** seperately, I don't want to divide **John : Doe**.
How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to "skip" a char, you either match it or not. Please describe the real life scenario. I guess it is a .NET regex, please tag appropriately.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match? Your current expression will match any character from `.` to `[` (ASCII code 46 to 91), which includes `0-9`, `A-Z` (but not `a-z` here), `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `@` and `/`.

Comment: To except character **":"** `[^:]`

Comment: It is a [valid .NET regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b%5cw.-%5b%5cd%5d%5d%5b%5cw.%5cs-%5b%5cd%5d%5d%2b%29%7c%28%5b0-9%5d%2b%29&i=Ab90) with character class subtraction. However, it just does not match `:`  - see [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b%5cw.-%5b%5cd%5d%5d%5b%5cw.%5cs-%5b%5cd%5d%5d%2b%29%7c%28%5b0-9%5d%2b%29&i=Ab90%3aCd). Thus, I am not sure what the question is about at all. Do you want to *match* it? Use `([\w.-[\d]][\w.:\s-[\d]]+)|([:0-9]+)`

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, I edited the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I edited the question.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now - use [`([\w.-[\d]][\w:.\s-[\d]]+)|([0-9]+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b%5cw.-%5b%5cd%5d%5d%5b%5cw%3a.%5cs-%5b%5cd%5d%5d%2b%29%7c%28%5b0-9%5d%2b%29&i=John+Doe%281%2f2%29%0d%0aJohn+%3a+Doe+%281%2f2%29), just add the `:` into the second character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `:` to the second character class to also match it:

```
([\w.-[\d]][\w:.\s-[\d]]+)|([0-9]+)
              ^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5B%5Cw.-%5B%5Cd%5D%5D%5B%5Cw%3A.%5Cs-%5B%5Cd%5D%5D%2B%29%7C%28%5B0-9%5D%2B%29&i=John%20Doe%281%2F2%29%0D%0AJohn%20%3A%20Doe%20%281%2F2%29)

Since the pattern presented some difficulties to SO audience, here is its explanation:

- `([\w.-[\d]][\w:.\s-[\d]]+)` - Group 1 capturing a sequence of:

  - `[\w.-[\d]]` - any Unicode letters, underscore or a `.` symbol - but NOT digits (since they are subtracted with `-[\d]`)
  - `[\w:.\s-[\d]]+` - 1 or more chars that are either Unicode letters, `:`, `.`, whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `([0-9]+)`  - Group 2 capturing 1 or more ASCII digits

To only match ASCII letters with the regex, compile the regex with the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get the two numbers in the brackets, which are separated by the slash, and the bit before that... and that's how you need to define your Regex. (Incidentally, the syntax of Regexes can vary, so it would help it you said what language you needed) I'd go for...

\(([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\)

which gives you "$1" as the first number, "$2" as the second number, and "$`" as everything before the bracketed section. Here is a unit test, demonstrating splitting the string into the 3 values (in C#, since no language has been specified):

```
    [TestCase("John Doe(1/2)", "John Doe", "1", "2")]
    [TestCase("John : Doe (1/2)", "John : Doe ", "1", "2")]
    public void TextExamples(string example, string expectedPart1, string expectedPart2, string expectedPart3)
    {
        // Arrange.
        Regex threePartPattern = new Regex(@"\(([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\)");

        // Act.
        Match threePartMatch = threePartPattern.Match(example);

        // Assert.
        Assert.That(threePartMatch.Success, Is.True);
        Assert.That(threePartMatch.Result("$`"), Is.EqualTo(expectedPart1));
        Assert.That(threePartMatch.Result("$1"), Is.EqualTo(expectedPart2));
        Assert.That(threePartMatch.Result("$2"), Is.EqualTo(expectedPart3));
    }
```

Comment: No, that is not what is necessary. Also, there is no need escaping `/` characters in the .NET regex.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited to remove the scape on /; but please explain why you said "that is not what is necessary".

Comment: Read the question, you will understand that. *I want to get `John : Doe` and `1` and `2` seperately*.

Comment: http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%28%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%2f%28%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%5c%29&i=John+%3a+Doe+%281%2f2%29

Comment: Posted a link to show that it does what is requested

Comment: Even at the regex testing site, you can  see it is not matching `John : Doe`.

Comment: I don't know what you're seeing but I see "John : Doe", "1" and "2" as three separate values.

Comment: Perhaps try doing what my answer says before saying it doesn't work.

Comment: But it does not validate the part before the match.